# id dynamic type documentation

Tags: objective-c

Can someone point me to the specific "id type documentation" ? I've been through the dynamic typing docs, but I want to know how to use the type id. Specifically how to check if id is null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `id` type is directly related to the Objective-C language itself, rather than the Cocoa/Cocoa Touch frameworks as your original tags implied. There is also no dynamic typing involved. [Here's a little introduction in Apple's docs.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html)

To answer your specific question, quoted from the above link:

> The keyword `nil` is defined as a null object, an `id` with a value of `0`. `id`, `nil`, and the other basic types of Objective-C are defined in the header file `objc/objc.h`.

`nil` and `NULL` are equivalent (zero pointers), and therefore interchangeable.

In a basic if statement, you just do this:

```
id myId = [[something alloc] init];

// Short for if (myId == nil)
if (!myId) {
    // myId is nil
} else {
    // myId is not nil
}
```

Comment: `id` is just like * in a path wildcard. It is often used in combination with categories to define a delegate type, e.g.: id<UITableViewDelegate>

Comment: What about the singleton object NSNull, when is that object used?. Thank you.

Comment: Got it Directly from Apple: "The NSNull class defines a singleton object you use to represent null values in situations where nil is prohibited as a value (typically in a collection object such as an array or a dictionary)."

Answer (score 1):

See [The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html) — specifically, the chapter on Objects, Classes and Messaging.

> In Objective-C, object identifiers are of a distinct data type: id. This type is the general type for any kind of object regardless of class and can be used for instances of a class and for class objects themselves. […]
>
> The keyword nil is defined as a null object, an id with a value of 0. id, nil, and the other basic types of Objective-C are defined in the header file objc/objc.h.

To compare variables by value, you simply use the == operator. So to test for nil, you do:

```
 someVariable == nil
```

Answer (score 1):

I've not seen it clearly stated in any other answers so I'll say it here:

an `id` is defined as a pointer to an object.

`nil` is zero cast as an id - (id)0 - as a result the following code:

```
NSString * myString = nil;
id idString = myString;
if (idString == nil) NSLog(@"idString == nil");
if (idString == NULL) NSLog(@"idString == NULL");
if (idString == (id)0) NSLog(@"idString == (id)0");
```

will have the following output:

```
2011-09-12 07:25:57.297 Sample Project[22130:707] idString == nil
2011-09-12 07:25:57.298 Sample Project[22130:707] idString == NULL
2011-09-12 07:25:57.299 Sample Project[22130:707] idString == (id)0
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I misunderstood your question, but wouldn't you just do something like:

```
// given
id sender;

if (sender == nil) {}
```

Basically you use `id` to catch any object that might be assigned to it. So you can do something like:

```
id name = [NSString stringWithString:@"john"];
```

and now name will be an `NSString` object, which you can verify by calling `[name class]`.

Take a look at the id section of [this page](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html) for more information.

Comment: Yes thats what I thought too, but I'm getting id objects set to [NSNull null] instead of just null, the "if(myIdVar)" check does not work... thats why I just wanted to make sure that its specific to what I'm doing.